# Windows cannot access Samba server - "not accessible"

Tags: 16.04, permissions, windows, samba

I created the secure Samba server. But in Windows when I try to use it, Windows gives me an error:

> `\\UBUNTU\folder` is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permission. Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Put at the end:

```
comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
   path = /home/ubuntu/ubuntu # The path to the folder
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 7777
```

Then create folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/ubuntu
sudo chown nobody.nogroup /home/ubuntu/ubuntu
```

Then try the Ubuntu IP address from Windows

Comment: that worked for me! Thank you for your help sir. Could you break down what the "create mask = 7777" does for me? "guest ok = yes" makes sens :-P.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I got this exact error when I set a value for the "LAN Manager Authentication Level" under the "Security Policy Manager" in windows. By default it is undefined. If you have set it accidently somehow, the only way to put it back to undefined (At least in Windows 10) is to delete the registry key.
The Reg Key and policy is described here.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-lan-manager-authentication-level